# Moving an A tag with a Div using JS on the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below I have four a tags then a div below consecutively.

```
<a href = "#community"> </a>
<div id = "community-container"></div>

<a href = "#gallery"> </a>
<div id = "gallery-container"></div>

<a href = "#homes"> </a>
<div id = "homes-container"></div>

<a href = "#customer"> </a>
<div id = "customer-container"></div>
```

I want to be able to move both the a tag with the matching/appropriate div using the DOM
such as

```
<a href = "#homes"> </a>
<div id = "homes-container"></div>

<a href = "#customer"> </a>
<div id = "customer-container"></div>

<a href = "#community"> </a>
<div id = "community-container"></div>

<a href = "#gallery"> </a>
<div id = "gallery-container"></div>
```

My idea was to set the attribute of each div to A1, D1 C1.... then change the order of the divs first using a for loop

```
$div_order = "A1C1G1B1E1D1H1";

for($i = 0; $i < $div_order.length; $i++){
$element = $div_order[$i];
$_temp = $($element); //Temporarily save the element
$($element).remove(); //Remove the element
$("#tab-cont-opt").append($_temp); //Reinsert the element in the correct 
order
$("#tab-cont-opt").append(" "); //Space
}
```

then add the a tags before to the appropriate div using the insertbefore() function...

this did not work...
lmk if u have any other ideas!

Comment: Why are you doing this with js instead of just changing your DOM?

Comment: Can you just wrap the two in another element (span?) and then just move that?

Comment: I am doing it on the DOM

Comment: I like the idea with the span let me try that